# ASP.NET MVC View Model with LINQ To Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

Let's say I create a query result

```
var query = from a in tblXYZ join c in tblABC on a.id = b.id select new {a.x, b.x};
```

What's the best way to pass that into a view? Should I create a new object and copy the query result into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's almost always the preferred mechanism to create a view-specific model.  I would also second @Marc's recommendation to materialize the query in the controller and pass the view to the list.  If you have an issue with a query it's much easier to diagnose if the query is executed in the controller rather than the view.  The stack trace is actually useful at that point.

Answer (score 1):

As presented, that will be an anonymous type, which *can* be accessed (even easier in 4.0 via `dynamic`) but it is ugly to do so. It also *currently* suffers from ambiguity over when the data access happens, as the LINQ is deferred, meaning that if you pass that *query* into the view, you are really doing you data access during the view (and not inside the controller).

I would be tempted to create a class to represent the data (essentially a view-model), and return a *list* of the entities (not a deferred query).

Comment: I recommend giving into temptation (at least in this case). :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where should I put this view-model (convention wise)?The view? The controller? A separate file?

Answer (score 0):

Put the query in repository. In controller pass the query result to the specified model-view for that view.

Model-View - a specified class for transferring data from controller to the view.